# Creating a Matrix of an Arbitrary number of Equations with Arbitrary number of Unknowns

Tags: python

I am new to python and have a rather challenging assignment from my Fluid Mechanics professor. I need to create a flow visualization of stream functions for a doublet sheet in uniform flow. This involves solving a system of equations to determine doublet strengths for an arbitrary number of doublets such that the streamline passing through the stagnation point resembles a NACA0018 airfoil.

Psi_uniform = U_inf*r*sin(theta)
Psi_doublet = -(k/2*pi)*(sin(theta)/r)

Assume that theta and r are known and converted from cartesian coordinates.

To solve for the doublet strength along the airfoil surface, I will need to have a system of equations that looks like this:

Psi_uniform(1) + Psi_doublet(1) + Psi_doublet(2) ... + Psi_doublet(n) == 0
Psi_uniform(2) + Psi_doublet(1) + Psi_doublet(2) ... + Psi_doublet(n) == 0
.
.
.
Psi_uniform(n) + Psi_doublet(1) + Psi_doublet(2) ... + Psi_doublet(n) == 0

Each Psi_doublet will be calculated using the known values and return that value multiplied by an unknown variable 'k(n)'

U_inf*r*sin(theta) - (k(1)/2*pi)*(sin(theta)/r) - (k(2)/2*pi)*(sin(theta)/r) ... -(k(n)/2pi)... == 0

The solution should return an array of k values K = [k(1), k(2), k(3), ... k(n)]

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been using MATLAB until recently. My professor has strongly recommended I switch to python.
Even in MATLAB I am struggling with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77503004/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to look up "panel methods". Note that most of the references use point vortices rather than doublets, which avoids one particular problem with your formulation: a doublet has a direction (which affects the definition of theta in your problem statement). You can find airfoil coordinates at airfoiltools.com. (I find it better to derive to rescale NACA0018 from NACA0012 if you use that site.) Alternatively, the 4-digit NACA airfoils have a precise analytic definition if you want to generate your own coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up “panel method”. Note that you are using source doublets rather than vortices to represent the aerofoil surface.

The idea is to replace your aerofoil surface by a set of “panels” with source doublets k<sub>j</sub>. Note that these source doublets are vectors – they have a direction perpendicular to the surface. I think it is probably easiest to take the panels as the lines joining successive vertices, the doublet positions as the centres of the lines, and the directions along the unit normals (n<sub>x</sub>,n<sub>y</sub>).

In your doublet stream function for panel point (x<sub>j</sub>,y<sub>j</sub>), the stream function at some other point (x,y) is

[image]

where Y<sub>j</sub> is the distance of (x,y) from the line along the doublet direction. It can be calculated as (e.g., by thinking of a component of the cross product):

[image]

[image]

The set of doublet strengths (k<sub>j</sub>) can be calculated by assuming that the entire aerofoil surface is the psi=0 streamline. Then, at the ith doublet point on the aerofoil:

[image]

or a matrix equation Mk=b,

[image]

which can be solved by, e.g., np.linalg.solve . (Note that the diagonal elements M<sub>ii</sub> are taken as zero.)

Once you have the set of doublet strengths you can calculate the stream function at any other point (x,y) in space (for example, a regular grid):

[image]

Then the streamlines are simply the contours of the stream function. You can create contours in Python with matplotlib.

Here is your NACA0018 aerofoil. The coordinates were downloaded from airfoiltools.com

[image]